# How to round a decimal value with an if statement

Tags: r, conditional-statements, rounding

I trying round decimal value using an `if` statement but I get an error:

> Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I trying make this in r

```
if(temp1 >= 0.1) {round(temp1, digits = 0)} else {return("///")}
```

In the result I must receive value "1"

Help me, please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works.  Ifelse seemed easier for this.  Is there a reason you wanted a function?

```
temp1 <- .001
ifelse(temp1 >= 0.1 , round(temp1, digits = 0), "///")

temp1 <- 1.2
ifelse(temp1 >= 0.1 , round(temp1, digits = 0), "///")
```

Alternatively you can use if and else loops (like you are doing)

```
if(temp1 >= 0.1) {
    round(temp1, digits = 0)
}else{
    "///"
}
```